# Print one line of an array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Ok, I have this array: $myarray en I want to print just the first element of it, later on the second, but not as a total array.

I'm trying this, but it gives me an error (Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/Kim/Sites/snooze/phpinclude/feedbackcontentday1.php on line 8)

```
foreach ($myarray as $value) {
                echo $value."";
                }
```

Here's the code from the array:

```
public function getFeedback($p_iUserid) {
    include("Connection.php"); //open db

    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT FeedbackPatient FROM tblFeedback 
                WHERE fk_UserId = ".$p_iUserid."";

        $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

        while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {
            $myarray[] = $row['FeedbackPatient'];
        }
            print_r($myarray);

        mysqli_free_result( $result );
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // no connection database
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: Where in your code is the foreach loop?

Comment: do a print_r($myarray) before passing it to foreach...you'll find that it is indeed NOT an array...hence "Invalid argument supplied" ...

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was something like:

```
foreach( $myarray as $key => $value ) {
  echo $value."";
  break;
}
```

Try this:

```
public function getFeedback($p_iUserid) {
    include("Connection.php"); //open db

    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT FeedbackPatient FROM tblFeedback WHERE fk_UserId = ".$p_iUserid."";

        $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

        $myarray = array( );

        while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {
            $myarray[] = $row['FeedbackPatient'];
        }
        print_r($myarray);

        mysqli_free_result( $result );
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // no connection database
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: The `$key =>` part is optional - you only need it if you want to look at the index in each loop.

Comment: Doesn't work, tried it before. Always get the same message: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/Kim/Sites/snooze/phpinclude/feedbackcontentday1.php on line 9

Comment: Didn't know that.. Than the array is probably broken.. Is your while-loop actually doing anything?

Comment: I agree the array may be broken, but when I print the whole array, there's no problem at all. :s

Comment: Ok, when is the array given to the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

First elememt starts with 0 therefore you can use...

```
// First element
echo $myarray[0];

// Second element
echo $myarray[1];
```